# Android translation animation for hiding views without changing visiblility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I need help with Animation. (My views are more sophisticated and i show you only main elements of my layout xml)

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/oneBigView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fourSmallViews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topLeft"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >                       
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topRight"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottomLeft"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show and hide some views:

1. There is no view visible
2. topLeft and topRight move out from the edges(topLeft from left, topRight from right) to the center of screen(parent).
3. When topLeft and topRight achieve half of their move bottomLeft and bottomRight shows exactly the same as topLeft and topRight in prev step
4. All four Views stays visible for few seconds.
5. topLeft and topRight move out from center of screen(parent)to the edges(topLeft to left, topRight to right).
6. When topLeft and topRight achieve half of their move bottomLeft and bottomRight move out exactly the same as topLeft and topRight in prev step
7. When all the views disappear oneBigView move from left edge and fills the screen.
8. oneBigView stays for few seconds.
9. oneBigView move from center to left edge of screen.
10. When oneBigView disappear everything starts over from 1.

[image: animation overview]

I tried do this but always something was not right:

1. I tried add some translate animations and changing the Visiblity(I tried View.INVISIBLE and VIEW.GONE) onAnimationEnd:

show

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate 
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500" />
    </set>
```

hide

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="500" />

    </set>
```

.java

```
final Animation leftIn=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.show);
final Animation leftOut=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hide);
leftIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //start animation for showing topRight bottomLeft and bottomRight 
            //with propper startOffset
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            left1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            leftOut.setStartOffset(4000);
            left1.startAnimation(leftOut);

        }
    });
leftOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            left1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

and so on... It worked perfectly for visibility but animation was not smooth at all (most of the time it works like i haven't use animation). When I stopped changing visiblity animation works correctly but it doesn't do the job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the alpha value of the views instead of making it invisible or gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `fillAfter` to both your `<set>` like this:

```
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
```

Setting visibilities with `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` generally dont work well with animations. Your only other option is to add a alpha animation to both `<set>`. Here's a template:

```
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="200"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
```

Adjust it as per your needs. Avoid setting visibilities.